# Execute command containing quotes from shell variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently having problems to execute a command from a shell variable.

In general the following works as expected:

```
COMMAND="echo A"
echo $COMMAND
$COMMAND
```

produces:

```
echo A
A
```

But if I do

```
COMMAND="su aUser -s /bin/bash -c 'echo A'"
echo $COMMAND
$COMMAND
```

I get

```
su aUser -s /bin/bash -c 'echo A'
Password: 
A': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
A': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I enter the line

```
su aUser -s /bin/bash -c 'echo A'
```

directly it works as expected.

It seems my assumption that $COMMAND is equal to entering the content as command directly is wrong.

### Questions

1) Does anyone know how I can run the command from a variable?

2) What exactly is the difference between

```
COMMAND="command"
$COMMAND
```

and

```
command
```

?

Comment: This is one of those common Don't Do That things.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050  A better approach is to use `set -x` if you want to see what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Didn't know the page yet.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Arrays are useful to keep your parameters whole:

```
command=(su aUser -s /bin/bash -c 'echo A')
```

and invoke it exactly like this:

```
"${command[@]}"
```

Comment: This works too... to sad that one cannot mark two answers as accepted.

Comment: That is better than `eval` but it will not work in Bourne Shell, only in `bash`

Comment: How I can put the output in a new variable from the command invoked like this?

Comment: @Mat, the same way you always store output from a command in a variable. `variable=$("${command[@]}")`

Answer (score 37):

You need `eval`.

```
$ eval $VARIABLE
```

Comment: Ok that works. Any hints what $COMMAND exactly does and why it is different to eval?

Comment: Avoid eval whenever possible, it has a reputation for being a source of weird bugs. If you must use it, at least double-quote the variable (i.e. eval "$VARIABLE"). Loosely speaking, $VARIABLE does some, but not all, of the normal parsing before executing; eval $VARIABLE does some parsing and then parses it again; eval "$VARIABLE" parses it exactly once.  But you're really better off using something like @glenn's answer.

Comment: `eval $VARIABLE` has bugs that would be avoided by using `eval "$VARIABLE"`. To demonstrate those bugs, try `VARIABLE=$'printf " - %s\\n" "first line" " * " "third line"'` and compare `eval`ing it both ways in a non-empty directory.

Comment: `eval ${command}` works even better handling escaped double quotes in the string variable.

Comment: @TimChaubet, that's not true. `eval "$command"` would be concretely better, but `eval $command` and `eval ${command}` are 100% identical.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 1. It's just best practice. `command="something"; echo "${command}123"; echo "$command123"` would yield a different outcome. 2. When the command has quotes, it yields different outcomes. `command='echo "Hello, World!"'`. Now run it with `$command` and with `${command}`. The first one will drop the embedded quotes. It is true, for more complex situations.

Comment: @TimChaubet, `$command` and `${command}` **both** treat the embedded quotes as literal rather than syntactic -- see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You're right that `$command123` is buggy when someone actually wants to expand `$command`, but that's the case where `${command}123` is actually useful and meaningful; it's not needed outside that corner case, and because that case relates to surrounding code rather than data, it's detectable at development time, making it unlike cases where best practices need to be followed to correctly handle all possible data.

Comment: @TimChaubet, in addition to the documentation previously linked, see the online sandbox at https://ideone.com/7IWQPi demonstrating that `$command` and `${command}` have identical output in the test case you proposed.