# Run a sed command depending on a variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed, switch-statement

I am trying to run a variable `sed` command depending on user input:

```
#!/bin/bash

ACTION=$1

if [ "wp" == "$ACTION"  ]
then
   MODIFIEDCONF='sed -i -e "/#Begin wp redirect/,/#End wp redirect/d" /root/test-conf'
else
   MODIFIEDCONF='sed -i -e "/#Begin ghost redirect/,/#End ghost redirect/d" /root/test-conf'
fi

RESULT=$($MODIFIEDCONF)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

How do I fix the error? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't think this is the root of your problem , but your comparison should only have a single equals sign. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash

Comment: Why you are creating variables? If you want to so see new edited file then simply print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple. Set your sed command pattern in a variable, then execute that.

```
case "$ACTION" in
wp) cmd="/#Begin wp redirect/,/#End wp redirect/d"       ;;
 *) cmd="/#Begin ghost redirect/,/#End ghost redirect/d" ;;
esac

sed -i "$cmd" /root/test-conf
```

or for a little more readability, just set the key and embed.

```
case "$ACTION" in
wp) key=wp    ;;
 *) key=ghost ;;
esac

sed -i "/#Begin $key redirect/,/#End $key redirect/d" /root/test-conf
```

Abstraction is power, but unnecessary abstraction is obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid doing variable expansion, ie running `$var`. And it's a custom to have UPPERCASE_VARIABLES beeing exported variables only, if you use variable only in your script use lowercase.
Why not like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get action
action=$1

# check action value
case "$action" 
wp) ;;
*) action=ghost; ;;
# or maybe: *) echo "ERROR: action has bad value! Exiting!" >&2; exit 1; ;;
esac

# run sed
result=$(sed -i -e "s/#Begin $action redirect/,/#End $action redirect/" /root/test-conf)
```

If you have to `result=$($modifiedconf)` use bash arrays:

```
if [ "wp" = "$action" ]; then
   modifiedconf=(sed -i -e "/#Begin wp redirect/,/#End wp redirect/d" /root/test-conf)
else
   modifiedconf=(sed -i -e "/#Begin ghost redirect/,/#End ghost redirect/d" /root/test-conf)
fi
result=$("${modifiedconf[@]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions to store code, not strings.

```
#!/bin/bash

ACTION=$1

if [ "wp" == "$ACTION"  ]
then 
   modify_conf() { sed -i -e "/#Begin wp redirect/,/#End wp redirect/d" /root/test-conf; }
else
   modify_conf() { sed -i -e "/#Begin ghost redirect/,/#End ghost redirect/d" /root/test-conf; }
fi

modify_conf
```

(`modify_conf` doesn't output anything useful, so there's no need to capture its output.)

Or pass `ACTION` as an argument:

```
modify_conf () {
  if [ "$1" = wp ]; then
    sed -i -e "/#Begin wp redirect/,/#End wp redirect/d" /root/test-conf
  else
    sed -i -e "/#Begin ghost redirect/,/#End ghost redirect/d" /root/test-conf
  fi
}

modify_conf "$ACTION"
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove the error you reported, you should change the line:

```
 RESULT=$($MODIFIEDCONF)
```

to:

```
 eval "$MODIFIEDCONF"
```

For more details about this, and references, see for example:

- [Execute command containing quotes from shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079342/execute-command-containing-quotes-from-shell-variable).
- [How to execute a bash command stored as a string with quotes and asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005192/how-to-execute-a-bash-command-stored-as-a-string-with-quotes-and-asterisk)

One caveat. The command `eval` does have a **bad** reputation: see for instance [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead). But in this case it is *perfectly safe*. The extra quotes in `eval "$MODIFIEDCONF"` (optional here) help protect from unexpected bugs.

---

Minor point: The `sed` command you wrote won't return any text (except maybe to `stderr`). If you really need a value for your variable `RESULT`, add the line:

```
  RESULT=$?
```

`$RESULT` will always be `0`, unless the file `/root/test-conf` does not exist (or if your script happens to have an invalid `sed` command, which is not the case here).