# A string containing a string, eg. SWITCHES="-b --excludes \"$FILENAME\""

Tags: string, bash, shell

I want to define a variable representing the switches for some program to be run later.  One of those switches needs a filename argument, where the filename may contain spaces or special characters.  How do I do something like this properly?

```
#! /bin/bash

FILE="/home/user/Excludes (1).txt"
SWITCHES="--verbose --exclude $FILE"  # both this and \"$FILE\" here fail.

someprogram $SWITCHES
```

Here is a real world example of trying to define a string in bash, that contains another string (though here the second one is an argument, rather than a switch):

```
$ cat > "foo bar"
me "foo bar"

$ FOOBAR="foo bar"
$ SWITCHES="-n $FOOBAR"

$ cat $SWITCHES
cat: foo: No such file or directory
cat: bar: No such file or directory

$ cat "$SWITCHES"
cat: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'cat --help' for more information.

$ SWITCHES="-n \"$FOOBAR\""

$ cat $SWITCHES
cat: '"foo': No such file or directory
cat: 'bar"': No such file or directory

$ cat "$SWITCHES"
cat: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Use an array instead of a string for this. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `switches=( --verbose --exclude "$file" )`, then `rsync "${switches[@]}"`

Comment: Note the use of lower case variable names -- that's specified by POSIX to prevent people from mistakenly overwriting names meaningful to the shell or operating system, which are all-caps.

Comment: I see.  Ok, thank you.  I feel like I should leave this question, because I couldn't find anything similar; but was it too simple?   Should I delete?  If not, and you don't want to, I could work up an answer.  @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better duplicate already in the knowledge base; I can try to find one to close it with something closer.

Comment: SWITCHES="-n \"$FOOBAR\""; eval cat $SWITCHES

Comment: That struck me as a cool hack, but now I understand we should [avoid 'eval'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11079387/1618452) if at all possible.