# BASH:Run a command stored in variable

Tags: bash, command, whiptail

I want to run a command with separate options, so i created a variable which contains the command with options..
I want to run this, but it doesnt work:

```
CHOICES=$("/usr/bin/whiptail $CHECKBOXCMD")
```

the command  `echo $CHECKBOXCMD` shows the good parameters, copied into shell it runs

> --title "Select the partitions to fill empty spaces with zeros" --checklist "NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE%" 20 98 4 "/dev/loop122p1" "ext4 b59e3c0c-f07d-4530-beb0-10d82cd2b8eb 539,2M
> 100%" ON

In the script i can get

> /usr/bin/whiptail --title "Select the partitions to fill empty spaces with zeros" --checklist "NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE%" 20 98 4  "/dev/loop122p1" "ext4         b59e3c0c-f07d-4530-beb0-10d82cd2b8eb  539,2M   100%" ON : No such file or directory

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: Don't use a variable for commands, variable holds data, function holds code, or use an array if you like storing code and execute it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079342/execute-command-containing-quotes-from-shell-variable

Comment: Also see why [Complex variable fails](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: your entire `whiptail` call is actually being processed as a single string (`'/usr/bin/whiptail ... 100%" ON'`) and thus the error message; remove the double quotes - `CHOICES=$(/usr/bin/whiptail $CHECKBOXCMD)` - to get around the current error message