# Eval executes command but command substitution breaks it

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "intented command:"
jq -n --argjson bar '{"test":"asdf"}' '$bar | .test'

foo="{\"test\":\"asdf\"}"
command="jq -n --argjson bar '$foo' '\$bar | .test'"
echo "Built command:"
echo $command
echo "Command execution with eval:"
eval $command
echo "Command execution with command substitution:"
$($command)
```

The first command works just fine and shows that the usecase is executable, also the outputed command by echo is exactly as in the original command in line 3, so I understand the escaping is working as intended.

`eval` evaluates the command stored in `command` just fine, but `$($command)` fails with the error message

```
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq
```

I would therefore expect that the escaping is somehow changes in `$($command)` but I could not identify why. Can anybody please explain?

Comment: Eval and $() are not the same, why would you want to do this tho, seems like an x/y problem.

Comment: I understand that eval combines all arguments given into a single command and evaluates this while allowing variable substitution (which causes the command to reevaluate). On the other hand, $() takes a single command and executes this i a new shell, replacing $() with the result - So I see why they are not the same, but don't understand why later does not work. I must use $() as it's part of a bigger context - above is only a broken down example.

Comment: [This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash) might help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute command containing quotes from shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079342/execute-command-containing-quotes-from-shell-variable) (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997135/bashrun-a-command-stored-in-variable)

Comment: Dno't embed code in a string. This is what *functions* are for.

Comment: All good comments/advice here and below, but I'm surprised that `$(cmd)` works in code that uses `#!/bin/sh` as its "shebang". Use `#!/bin/bash` instead. Good luck.

Comment: You may get `cmd="command stored in variable"` to work for this case, but you're setting yourself up for trouble if you use this as your primary implementation pattern in shell scripting. You will find a point that you've spent hours trying to get some crazy thing to work and ultimately have to give up. It's just not worth it. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter why wouldn't it work? `$(...)` is POSIX and has been supported by any shell for the last 30 years or so.

Comment: Just some old-school advice (-; `#/bin/sh` used to mean "the Borne Shell", which is definitely not Posix. It may also mean, `ash`, `dash` which I don't think are Posix. If you wind up having to use Busybox, you won't have Posix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody please explain?

Quotes are **not** taken into account when evaluating unquoted variable substitution. Unquoted variable expansion splits on white spaces unconditionally and executes filename expansion and preserves quote literally.

```
a="echo 'a b'"
$a  # executes command 'echo' with two arguments "'a" "b'".
```

The string `'{"test":"asdf"}'` **with** the quotes preserved, i.e. `"'{\"test\":\"asdf\"}'"` in shell quoted format, is not a valid json.

Do not store commands as a string. Use `set -x` to debug shell scripts. Consider re-reading a bash scripting introduction, check how to create functions, and check bash arrays.

Check your scripts with shellcheck to protect against such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, this combined with a detailed read of https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments helped. Eventually, I had my quotes wrong and this worked: `command="jq -n --argjson bar $foo  "'$bar | .test'" "`

Comment: Kindly note that the part` `"'$bar | .test'"`  is in conflict with the recommendation "Do not store commands as a string".